# Javascript is not working on dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html

```
         <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

                </head>

                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" >
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.9.2/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
                    <script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
                    <script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
                    <script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
                    <script src="jquery-ui-1.9.2/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.9.2/demos/demos.css">





                <!-- data picker js code goes here -->           

                <!-- Add dynamic content your form js code goes here -->



                <body>

                <div style="margin:10%;" >

                <table class="table table-list table-striped"  style="width:40%;">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>S.No</th>
                                    <th>Title</th>

                                    <th>Cost</th>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th>Net</th>
                                    <th>Vat(%)</th>
                                    <th>Gross</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="row_div">
                                <tr>

                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="title" class="input-medium" name="title" cost_class="title"/></td>

                                    <td><input type="text" id="cos" class="input-medium" name="cost" cost_class="cost_type"/></td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" class="date_Picker" name="date1" date_class="date_type"/></td>
                                     <td><input type="text" id="des" class="test" name="description" description_class="description_type" /></td>
                                     <td><input type="text" id="net" name="Net" class="num1" onchange="gross_amount()" ></td>
                                     <td><input type="text" id="vat" name="Vat" class="num2" onchange="gross_amount()"></td>
                                     <td><input type="text" id="gross" name="Gross" class="sum"></td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                                    <div class="row" style="margin-left:20px;"><a href="javascript:add_tr();">Add</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                            <a href="javascript:remove_tr();">Remove</a>
                                    </div>
                </div>







<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {

                            $(document).on("click",".date_Picker",function(){        

                                    $(this).datepicker({                        
                                            changeMonth: true,
                                            changeYear: true,
                                            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'                       
                                        }).datepicker("show");
                                });

                    });






                var intTextBox=1;
                //FUNCTION TO ADD File BOX ELEMENT
                function add_tr()
                {
                    if(intTextBox>0)
                    {

                intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
                var contentID = document.getElementById('row_div');
                var newtr = document.createElement('tr');
                newtr.setAttribute('id','floorstrText'+intTextBox);
                newtr.innerHTML = "<td>"+intTextBox+"</td><td><input type='text' id=title" + intTextBox + " name=title" + intTextBox + " class='input-medium' cost_class='cost_type'/></td><td><input type='text' id=cos" + intTextBox + " name=cost" + intTextBox + " class='input-medium' cost_class='cost_type'/></td><td><input  name=date"+ intTextBox +" type='text' class='date_Picker input-medium'  id=dat"+ intTextBox +" date_class='date_type'/></td><td><input type='text' id=des" + intTextBox + " name=des" + intTextBox + " description_class='description_type' /></td><td><input  name=Net"+ intTextBox +" type='text' class='num2 key'  id=net"+ intTextBox +" /></td><td><input  name=Vat"+ intTextBox +" type='text' class='num2 key'  id=dat"+ intTextBox +" /></td><td><input  name=Gross"+ intTextBox +" type='text' class='sum'  id=gross"+ intTextBox +"/></td>";
                contentID.appendChild(newtr);
                    }

                }

                //FUNCTION TO REMOVE TEXT BOX ELEMENT
                function remove_tr()
                {
                    if(intTextBox != 0)
                    {
                    var contentID = document.getElementById('row_div');
                    contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById('floorstrText'+intTextBox));
                    intTextBox = intTextBox-1;
                    }
                }


                            function gross_amount() {
                            var Net = parseInt(document.getElementById("net").value);
                            var Vat = parseInt(document.getElementById("vat").value);
                            var Gross = Net+((Vat*Net)/100);

                            document.getElementById("gross").value = Gross;
                }
                </script>


                </body>
                </html>
```

gross_amount function works perfectly on first but when i try to calculate gross amount in duplicate row  javascript does not work for another rows.Plz help on this script as soon as possible.If Possible plz give me the jsfiddle link.
            Thankyou in Advance.......

Comment: have checked in console for bugs? try to put function gross_amount in header section

Comment: also call your css and js file either in header section or in body. post clean and neat code

Comment: I have tried but this doesn't work @Atul

Comment: create fiddle using your code

Answer (score 0):

what **dynamic table** means? In the *grossAmount* function you are going to select always the same element by **id**... if others elements are appendend on the dom they need to have a different id element...
With your function you'll get always the same.

#### Note, you are using jQuery.ui but I don't see jQuery in your dom, before all jQuery.ui components you have to load jQuery.

try something like that:

```js
function FormCtrl($) {
  var self = this;

  
 
  self.form = $('#foo');
  self.addRowToTheForm = function() {
    var row = $('.table-row', self.form).first().clone();
    
    row.find('input').val(0);
    
    return $('tbody', self.form).append(row);
  };

  self.onValueChange = function(event, row) {
    var vat = Number($('.form-control-vat', row).val()) || 0;
    var net = Number($('.form-control-net', row).val()) || 0;
    var result = net * ( (vat * net) / 100);
    
    
    $('.table-row-result', row).val(result);
  };
  
  $('#addRow').click(self.addRowToTheForm);
  self.form.on('change', 'input', function(event) {
    var row = $(this).closest('.table-row');
    
    return self.onValueChange(event, row);
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(FormCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="foo">
  <thead>
    <tr><th colspan="3"><button id="addRow">Add a Row</button></th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-row">
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control-vat" placeholder="VAT"/></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control-net" placeholder="NET"/></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="table-row-result" placeholder="Result" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```